# Java ternary operator precedence ? Different outputs given

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have the below code producing this output (**no space after -1**) ==> `"1 3 -14 -15 -1"`

```
int [] arr = {1, 3, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 4, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 5, Integer.MAX_VALUE};
for (int dist : arr) {
    System.out.print((dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : dist + " ");
}
```

But if I evaluate the ternary expression separately (as shown below), it gives a different output (what I expected) ==> `"1 3 -1 4 -1 5 -1"`

```
int [] arr = {1, 3, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 4, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 5, Integer.MAX_VALUE}; 
for (int dist : arr) {
    int finalDist = (dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : dist;
    System.out.print(finalDist + " ");          
}
```

What is going wrong with the first code snippet?

Comment: Operator precedence: + comes befores ? so with added redundant parentheses, your line is `dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : (dist + " ")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here

```
(dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : dist + " "
```

The space will be added only if the condition is `false`. You should use parantheses to add `" "` at all times like below.

```
((dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : dist) + " "
```

The ternary operator has only operator precedence over the assignment operators. (See below)

---

### [Oracle Site about Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

> The operators in the following table are listed according to
>   precedence order. The closer to the top of the table an operator
>   appears, the higher its precedence.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple problem with your parentheses. Try this:

```
int [] arr = {1, 3, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 4, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 5, Integer.MAX_VALUE};

    for (int dist : arr) {
        System.out.print(((dist == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : dist) + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You missed to put the operation within parenthesis, so it is behaving weirdly, use below code,

```
try{
        throw new ArithmeticException("Exception Testing...");
    }catch(Exception e){
        String msg = "First Statement : " + (e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : null);

        System.out.println(msg);
     }
```

In case you need any other help or explanation on this . Please let me know.

Comment: You seem to have answered the wrong question. You probably meant to answer  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672066/ternary-operation-behaves-weirdly), which is marked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: why did u marked it as -1 , i have posted so he can get his answer here, as i'm unable to drop my resolution there.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as an answer to this question. Future visitors will see completely different code than is asked above. And there is no need to answer the old one, as the answer can be found in existing answers to this question.