# ternary operation behaves weirdly

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

I have a difficulty in understanding how the ternary operation works in the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            throw new ArithmeticException("Exception Testing...");
        }catch(Exception e){
            msg = "First Statement : " + e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : null;  //Here e.getCause() is null
            System.out.println(msg);  //  prints "Exception Testing..."
         }
    }
```

In the `first Statement` `block(Line 4), e.getcause()` is null so it should print `First Statement: null` instead it prints only `Exception Testing...`.

My question is,

1)Why TRUE block got executed in the ternary operation instead of returning null and also,

2)Why `First Statement:` is not printed with the msg `Exception Testing...`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"First Statement : " + e.getCause()` is not null, so `"First Statement : " + e.getCause() != null` is true.

Comment: There is a duplicate for this question. I just can't find it.

Comment: `e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : null` makes little sense. You probably meant `e.getCause() == null ? e.getMessage() : e.getCause().getMessage()`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  i meant this only. e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : null. cause i know e.getCause() is null. i just wanted to know why e.getMessage() executed.

Comment: @Arun I keep removing your "thank you" to Andi :) it's not really needed, you may accept his answer instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of operator precedence, `+` is applied before `?:`, so you are checking whether:

```
"First Statement : " + e.getCause()
```

is null - it's not.

Add parentheses:

```
 msg = "First Statement : " + (e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : null);
```